I was working on testnet but I'm lacking BTC ammount, can anyone help me please?
I was working a testnet project which requires Taproot btc , But I'm lacking of it, I need around 0.1 BTC, can anyone please help me? it will be a big help>>
tb1pjx30lagtgfeh6vkuqtwx5jzttsg3qnvtp3sdvre7vqkx3rjwc95qwf3d6t

This question is similar to: How can I get more than 1 BTC on testnet?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
